# VB2008 : Get filename of a form?

Tags: .net, vb.net, forms, types, filenames

How can I get the file name of a form in run time ?

```
Label1.Text = " Form name is : " & Me.Name
Label2.Text = " File name is : " & ?????
```

Comment: This might not be possible as the filename is most likely lost in compilation. Me.GetType().ToString() might give you something similar.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the Vb compiler does not store that information, sorry.

However, if you are compilling (in debug or release mode) creating the debug information **.pdb** files, then you can get the filenames from the symbols, but that does not seems the idea that you have in mind because you should ship the pdb files with your binaries and perform the effort to reflect this info.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean, getting the filename of the executable

```
Label1.Text = " Form name is : " & Me.Name
Label2.Text = " File name is : " & Application.ExecutablePath
```